# Convert Dictionary having array value for keys into a list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, arraylist

I have a dictionary structure as follows : 
`data = { a : [5, 10], b : [1, 12] , c : [6, 7]}`

I need to convert this to follows : 
`[ a, 5, 10 ], [ b, 1, 12 ],  [ c, 6, 7 ]`

I've already tried using Object.entries(data), but it returned the data like : `[a, [5, 10]], [b, [1, 12]]`

How can i do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could map the key/values in a new array.

```js
var data = { a : [5, 10], b : [1, 12] , c : [6, 7]},
    result = Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [k, ...v]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```js
const  data = { a : [5, 10], b : [1, 12] , c : [6, 7]};
const result = Object.entries(data).map(pair => pair.flat());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

So with `Object.keys()` and `reduce()` you can solve as the following:

```js
const data = { a: [5, 10], b: [1, 12], c: [6, 7] };
const result = Object.keys(data).map(e => {
  return data[e].reduce((a, c) => {
    a.push(c);
    return a;
  }, Array.from(e));
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = { 'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb' };
var arr = [];

for (var key in dict) {
    if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push( [ key, dict[key] ] );
    }
}
```

this might helps you out